# Selecting different types of charts

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, highcharts

Is it possible to allow a user to select from a dropdown list the type of chart they'd like their data to be displayed as? If so, how could it be implemented?

Comment: Sure it is, but it will be rather complicated as the different chart types accepts different data formats etc. Just look at the examples on Highcharts website, and construct different data models based on what chart the user selects

Comment: Oh great!, would it be something you would suggest doing?, or do you think having each different chart available but in a different menu would be the easier option?

Comment: I really have no idea, that's up to you, and you have test it yourself !

Comment: There is a working example on the highcharts forums!, only it uses an older version. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely do that using highcharts.

Here is a working example from highcharts forum

you can use options of series

the method `series.update()` can be used to achieve your target.

here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/Zyv94/) directly from the forum.